# UpdatePanel does not trigger in SharePoint 2013 Visual webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Unable to understand why does Update Panel does do the soft post back (partial post back).
Nothing happens on page after the dropdownlist selected Index change.
tried to ref :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx

Would be thankful if any already cracked up the isse for SharePoint 2013.

request is processed on dropdown change without any exception but does not reflects UI

Answer (score 0):

you should check your trigger, perhaps you dont have it, or its not referencing the control properly

take a look here, and if you need, make a post over there

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110432/sharepoint-2013-webpart-timer-not-tick/110436#110436

Comment: my updatepanel mode is set to updatemode='always' which means i dont need  trigger or any ticker for this.